# How to sort an array of CUDA vector types

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust, cub

Specifically how could I sort an array of `float3`? Such that the `.x` components are the primary sort criteria, the `.y` components are the secondary sort criteria and the `.z` components are the tertiary sort criteria.

Is there a simple solution that can make a single call to `cub:: DeviceRadixSort` or `thrust::sort_by_key`?

At the moment I am thinking maybe I could create a `uint32` key array where the each element has the first third of its digits taken from the first third of the input array's `.x` components, the second third of digits taken from the first third of the input array's `.y` components, and the final third of its digits taken from the first third of the input array's `.z` components. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could use a method like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597224/sorting-packed-vertices-with-thrust).  Do you need a `sort_by_key` ?  It's not clear to me from this question that you do.  You simply need to construct a thrust functor that establishes the ordering rule you want.

Comment: Your right. I don't need the key, I just thought it would be a useful tool to avoid extracting individual elements. The solution you pointed to looks very useful although I am not particularly familiar with functors. Do you have a good reference/example for these? Particularly something that explains the arguments of the functor?

Comment: a functor is a c++ function object.  If you google that, you will find many reference guides like [this one](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).  It's not a thrust -specific concept.  Also the thrust [quick start guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) is useful although it doesn't focus on functors specifically.  Functors are fairly essential tools if you want to do thrust programming.  But apart from that, a trivial modification of the example I previously linked could be used to sort an array of `float3` in thrust.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob, I think I am on the way to a working solution. Appreciate the help. Time for me to become functor savy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597224/sorting-packed-vertices-with-thrust) that [Robert Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695960/robert-crovella) suggested I have crafted the following solution. Thanks again Rob.

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

struct sort_float3 {
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const float3 &a, const float3 &b) const {

    if      (a.x <= b.x && a.y <= b.y && a.z < b.z) return true;
    else if (a.x <= b.x && a.y < b.y) return true;
    else if (a.x < b.x) return true;
    else return false;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    float3 *h_array;
    // Define your host array
    float3 *d_array;
    cudaMallocHost( (void**)&d_array,
                    number_of_elements * sizeof(float3) );      
    cudaMemcpy( d_array,
                h_array, 
                number_of_elements * sizeof(float3),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    thrust::device_ptr<float3> th_array( d_array );
    thrust::sort( th_array, 
                  th_array+number_of_elements , 
                  sort_float3() );
    return 0;
}
```