# CUDA Thrust sort large datatype(512 byte)

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have an array of a large datatype (integer) consisting of 512 bytes per element which i would like to sort with the CUDA thrust library using radix sort. However i struggle to find out how i can provide the size of the elements to thrust.

I assume there should be a quite simple way to do this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: You won't be able to easily use radix sort.  Thrust only uses radix sort for types it can identify.  For other types of sorting it uses a different algorithm, that I think is merge-based.  If you want to use the non-radix sort in thrust, it should be just a matter of providing an appropriate type definition, and then providing a functor that knows how to order two elements of that type.

Comment: It's not identical to your case, but [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597224/sorting-packed-vertices-with-thrust) lays out a basic thrust approach to doing an arbitrary data type sort.